# Hotkey to give suggestion list of an instance's methods while coding

Tags: java, eclipse, user-experience, hotkeys

In general, I dislike it when `Eclipse` will give me suggestions of methods when I am typing `objectInstance.` (at which point the list drops down). Thus I have disabled this feature. However there *are times* when I want this suggestion list.

Is there a hotkey where I can, on demand, call this suggestion list. Neither switching it off completely or having it on all the time is what I want.

Comment: Have you tried Crtl + space?

Comment: @enterbios This seems to be the answer. Want to post it?

Comment: @user2763361 Please accept the answer to close your question

Comment: @Octopus Need to wait 9 mins :)

Comment: ha ha, Oh, Stackoverflow wants to make more users to answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> is hotkey you're looking for.